# Grouped TableView scroll issue in IOS 7.0?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scrollview

I have created grouped `UITableView` with custom cells.in custom cell i have added `UITextfield` and text field did begin editing moving tableview scroll to top to display textfield above keyboard.Its working fine in ios 6.0 but in ios 7.0 tableview moving down so keyboard hides textfield

My tried code is below

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {

        cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[[[textField superview] superview] superview]superview];
    }
    else
    {
        cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[[textField superview] superview]superview];
    }

    [self.TableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetMinY(cell.frame)) animated:YES];
}
```

Please help me if anyone know.Thanks n advance.

Answer (score 1):

Add this method in your ViewController

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews 
{
   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
   yourtableviewname.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

i hope this code useful for you.